# How to pass React state to a nested component within another component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jsx

I have a user component that makes an API to get info and then stores it in state.  The problem is I cannot figure out how to pass the state into another component inside this component `<FormInputs>`

So, after the call, I need to have the params from `state: users[]` to be able to show up in the ``defaultValue``` property in the child component.  How do I do this?  I have tried many different ways but always "undefined"

I tried this as well: `` defaultValue: `${users.email} `` No dice.  Also tried `this.props.users.email` No dice.  Thanks in advance for a possible hint!

```
import axios from 'axios';

import {
  Grid,
  Row,
  Col,
  FormGroup,
  ControlLabel,
  FormControl
} from "react-bootstrap";

import { Card } from "components/Card/Card.jsx";
import { FormInputs } from "components/FormInputs/FormInputs.jsx";
import { UserCard } from "components/UserCard/UserCard.jsx";
import Button from "components/CustomButton/CustomButton.jsx";

import avatar from "assets/img/faces/face-3.jpg";

class UserProfile extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
 
    this.state = {
      users: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://niftyAPIurlDataCall/AlltheThings')
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
      const users = response.data;
      this.setState({ users });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="content">
        <Grid fluid>
          <Row>
            <Col md={8}>
              <Card
                title="Edit Profile"
                content={
                  <form>
                    <FormInputs
                      ncols={["col-md-5", "col-md-3", "col-md-4"]}
                      properties={[
                        {
                          label: "Lab (disabled)",
                          type: "text",
                          bsClass: "form-control",
                          placeholder: "Lab",
                          defaultValue: "account",
                          disabled: true
                        },
                        {
                          label: "ID",
                          type: "text",
                          bsClass: "form-control",
                          placeholder: "ID",
                          defaultValue: users.id
                        },
                        {
                          label: "Email address",
                          type: "email",
                          bsClass: "form-control",
                          placeholder: "Email",
                          defaultValue: `${users.email}`
                        }
                      ]}
                    />
                    <FormInputs
                      ncols={["col-md-6", "col-md-6"]}
                      properties={[
                        {
                          label: "First name",
                          type: "text",
                          bsClass: "form-control",
                          placeholder: "First name",
                          defaultValue: `${users.first_name}`
                        },
                        {
                          label: "Last name",
                          type: "text",
                          bsClass: "form-control",
                          placeholder: "Last name",
                          defaultValue: `${users.last_name}`
                        },
                        {
                          label: "User ID",
                          type: "text",
                          bsClass: "form-control",
                          placeholder: "Last name",
                          defaultValue: `${users.user_id}`
                        }
                      ]}
                    />
                    <FormInputs
                      ncols={["col-md-12"]}
                      properties={[
                        {
                          label: "Group",
                          type: "text",
                          bsClass: "form-control",
                          placeholder: "Group",
                          defaultValue: `${users.group}`
                        },
                        {
                          label: "Group ID",
                          type: "text",
                          bsClass: "form-control",
                          placeholder: "Group ID",
                          defaultValue: `${users.group_id}`
                        },
                        ,
                        {
                          label: "Join date",
                          type: "text",
                          bsClass: "form-control",
                          placeholder: "Join date",
                          defaultValue: `${users.join_date}`
                        }
                      ]}
                    />
                    <Button bsStyle="info" pullRight fill type="submit">
                      Update Profile
                    </Button>
                    <div className="clearfix" />
                  </form>
                }
              />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UserProfile;
```

Comment: is a single user returned or multiple from your API call?

Comment: if users is an array [ ] you need to use the element index defaultValue: `${users[index].email}

Comment: Yes.  Single user.  Thanks for Hint Leigh

Comment: Just one user is returned, not many.  The array contains values like id, email, firstname, lastname, etc. Have tried freaking everything.  I am just missing knowledge on how to do this.

Comment: The first thing I would do here is console log out what the state looks like after the api call. Even if it's a single user, it could be in an array, so you might need to do `users[0].email` or something. It looks like the state is set up to expect an array.

Comment: Agree with @JordanDavis about logging the state to see what is going on. But I suspect the inputs are rendering before the axios call comes back, and the inputs' "defaultValue" is already set (to undefined) and won't be overwritten by future state changes. If that is the case, skip rendering the form until the axios call completes.

Comment: Hello all, the thing here is that it's not an array, it's just the user data from an authentication call....so we only get back one record, and it seems to be a JSON structure like so:

{ "id": "blah", "name": "name" }.  So I changed setState in constructor to {} instead of []. still nothing.  I think the data is there, as I can get it if I put these called OUTSIDE the other component in the render... i..e if I put "this.props.users.id". outside FormInput it renders.....put it inside the child component...nada

Comment: I would try @LincolnAnderson's suggestion and use a boolean `loaded` flag in the state, set it to true after the api call resolves, and then use `{ loaded && <Card...` etc.